# automatic Y-axis scale: max is always as 120% of highest value in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS 2.7.2.

Now Y-axis scale is automatic depending on values. I want it to be still automatic but max should not be too high.
I always want to see max scale at for example: (value+20%).

desired look:
[good looking chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwDym.png)

unwanted look:
[not so good looking chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcNwA.png)

/edited:

[example with data](https://jsfiddle.net/kruzyk/c0nwokt9/12/)

I'm using ajax to get data: [my real JS code](https://jsfiddle.net/kruzyk/c0nwokt9/19/)

I want to see only 3 Y-axis ticks ([screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkZdu.png)) but scale and line should look like here ([screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k33FC.png)).

How it looks without `maxTicksLimit: 3,`:
[screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k33FC.png)

How it looks with `maxTicksLimit: 3,`:
[screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkZdu.png)

Comment: Do you have a sample with some sample data that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Please post your code or better create a fiddle

Comment: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/kruzyk/c0nwokt9/12/)

Comment: When I remove `maxTicksLimit: 3,` it works fine - so mayby I should find other way of showing only 3 ticks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a backend language to parse the data prior to displaying it, I'd be doing a calculation there to work out what the "max" figure should be, then insert that into the yTicks are as "max: " (as a PHP example), otherwise, use javascript .forEach to cycle through your data array and determine the highest number, then put that in the max field.